# Random StorageException while sending message to Azure Storage Queue (Not always)

Tags: android, exception, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I am getting the following exception randomly when I try to send some message to the Cloud Queue of Azure Storage. I am using version 0.5.1 of the azure storage client library for android.  I am not using SAS, instead I am using Azure Account name and key. Please help me solving this issue.

> com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:307) at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:181) at com.microsoft.azure.storage.queue.CloudQueue.exists(CloudQueue.java:887) at com.microsoft.azure.storage.queue.CloudQueue.createIfNotExists(CloudQueue.java:526) at com.microsoft.azure.storage.queue.CloudQueue.createIfNotExists(CloudQueue.java:501)

**Edit:**
Here is my code which caused the exception. As I said it works fine sometimes, the exception happens randomly.

```
    try
    {
        // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
                CloudStorageAccount.parse(STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);

        // Create the queue client.
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.createCloudQueueClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a queue.
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.getQueueReference(QUEUE);

        // Create the queue if it doesn't already exist.
        queue.createIfNotExists();

        // Create a message and add it to the queue.
        CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(msg);
        queue.addMessage(message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Output the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Is this happening intermittently with the same storage connection string or a different storage connection string each time? Could you verify your account key?

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft, I am using the same storage connection string each time. I verified the account key. This exception happens sometimes only, otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Could you provide some additional information such as either the client side or service side logs for a failing request? Client side logging can be turned on in the OperationContext and logs to logcat as is standard with Android. Service side logging can be turned on in the Azure Portal or in code using the uploadServiceProperties API on the client object. Service side logs are stored in blobs which are easily accessible via the helpers in the analytics package of the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to troubleshoot further by using the following guides:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-e2e-troubleshooting/